# Why do podcasters and writers do this - use of would?

Tags: tenses, backshifting, will-be-going, will-would, future-in-past

I was listening to a true crime podcast this morning and it reminded me of several others I have heard in the past. They repetitively refer to an action that was going to happen after the point in the story about which they are talking.  Example: "The gangster would later tell his homie..." or "A week later, he would get arrested" "He would soon come under suspicion." "On June 9, 2020, he would be shot in the chest".  I mean in the one I tried listening to this morning, the guy used this way or writing pretty much every sentence.  I had to turn it off.

Okay, so my question is, what tense is that?  As a long time audiobook lover, that is anomalous to what I normally hear in narration. If it were me, I would write the following: "The gangster later told his homie." Or "He later got arrested.  "..soon came under suspicion." etc.

I'm not a great writer so please let me know if they're correct here and what tense that is?  If i had been the editor, I would have done everything I could to dissuade the writer/narrator from using that "tense" when simple was available to him.

Comment: It's the [Future in the Past](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html). *Pami hoped that **someone would answer the question*** (at the time of posting the question, any possible answers lay in the future).

Comment: The problem with using Simple Past is it forces the "narrative reference time" forward to the later event. Usually the narrator won't want to do that, especially if he needs to reference *other* elements in the narrative, happening in between the two timeframes linked by Future in the Past. Your approach would probably introduce serious temporal anomalies, and/or force the writer to be constantly switching from Simple Past to Past Perfect.

Comment: I think it sounds odd because in most past-tense narrative, the story is told as it happens, maybe with references to earlier events when they need to be described, but not normally with references to later events. It might be considered a distinctive story-telling style or trope (and maybe it's particularly associated with true crime podcasts) to break with this convention and include references to later events, but there's nothing ungrammatical about it: you have to use the appropriate tenses for later events.